# Quotient Rule In Multivariable Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$f(x,y)=\frac{9x}{x^2+5y}$$

To take the partial derivative with respect to $y$ should we use the quotient rule? as $$f(x,y)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x,y)}$$

Answer (score 1):

here is $x$ a constant, thus we get
$$f_y=\frac{-9x\cdot 5}{(x^2+5y)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can view the numerator as a multi-variate function also, $g(x,y) = 9x$. Anyways, it proceeds the same as it does in the case of a single variable (holding $x$ as a constant). The partial derivative

$$f_y = \dfrac{0(x^2 + 5y) - 5(9x)}{(x^2 + 5y)^2} = \dfrac{-45x}{(x^2 + 5y)^2}$$